# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' over night with no change in code

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

Our Python build have failed during the last night when there was no change in code.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MY_PACKAGE/MY_FILE_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Our only dependency of MY_PACKAGE is `grpcio (>=1.9.1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found out that the reason is the removal of `protobuf` dependency from `grpcio` latest version:

Package grpcio 1.11.0 metadata:

```
"run_requires": [{"requires": ["six (>=1.5.2)"]}]
```

Package grpcio 1.12.0 metadata:

```
"run_requires": [{"requires": ["protobuf (>=3.5.0.post1)", "six (>=1.5.2)"]}]
```

So it is necessary to add `protobuf` dependency manually.